# Why does libarchive's bsdtar's unzip throw away the permission bits when reading a ZIP-archive from stdin, but not directly?

Tags: executable, zip, stdin, archive

I encountered that the command `bsdtar` from the package `libarchive` (under Arch Linux, at least) does throw away executable bits of files in `.zip`-archives when reading from `stdin`, but not when directly working on the file.

On `.tar`-archives it preserves the executable bit also when reading from stdin.

### Test case:

#### Create the archives:

Create the files:

```
touch a.txt
chmod 644 a.txt
touch a.out
chmod 755 a.out
```

The file permissions:

```
ls -ln a.out a.txt
```

shows

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1001 1001 0 Dec 12 11:01 a.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001 0 Dec 12 11:01 a.txt
```

Pack the files into archives:

```
bsdtar --format=zip -cf a.zip a.out a.txt
bsdtar -cf a.tar a.out a.txt
```

(Creating the archives with `zip` and `tar` instead of `bsdtar` produces the same result.)

#### Extracting/ showing the archive content directly:

```
bsdtar -tvf a.zip
```

or

```
bsdtar -tvf - < a.zip
```

shows

```
-rwxr-xr-x  0 1001   1001        0 Dec 12 11:01 a.out
-rw-r--r--  0 1001   1001        0 Dec 12 11:01 a.txt
```

The executable bit of `a.out` is present here.
The permissions of `a.out` are 755 and of `a.txt` 644.

#### Reading from `stdin`:

```
cat a.zip | bsdtar -tvf -
```

shows

```
-rw-rw-r--  0 1001   1001        0 Dec 12 11:01 a.out
-rw-rw-r--  0 1001   1001        0 Dec 12 11:01 a.txt
```

The executable bit for `a.out` is thrown away here.
Furthermore, both files are group-writeable, they were not packed that way.
The permissions of `a.out` and `a.txt` are both 664.

#### `.tar`-archive:

As a comparison, for a `.tar`-archive, the permissions in the archive are also honoured when reading from a pipe from `stdin`:

```
bsdtar --numeric-owner -tvf a.tar
```

and

```
cat a.tar | bsdtar --numeric-owner -tvf -
```

both show

```
-rwxr-xr-x  0 1001   1001        0 Dec 12 11:01 a.out
-rw-r--r--  0 1001   1001        0 Dec 12 11:01 a.txt
```

(note that, when showing the contents of a ZIP archive, `bsdtar` shows the numeric owner by default; for a TAR archive it shows the name of the owner.)

The question is:

What is special with `stdin` with regard to `bsdtar`? And why only when reading from a pipe, and not in the fashion `bsdtar -tvf - < a.zip`? And why special to a `.zip`-archive, but not to a `.tar`-archive?

Comment: i think the answer is in the source code.

Comment: I'm mostly surprised that `bsdtar` read a Zip archive without complaining...

Comment: @Kusalananda `bsdtar` (which is FreeBSD's `tar`) can both create and extract zip files (and a lot of other archive formats).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here on the bugtracker of `libarchive`](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/issues/1106#issuecomment-446219915) is the answer:

> Zip archives contains two different ways to describe the content:
>
> 1. A per-entry header
> 2. A central directory at the end of the zip file.
>
> libarchive (and bsdtar by extension) will use the central directory if seeking is possible on the input, otherwise it will fall back to the streaming-only logic. The entries are not necessarily consistent as you found out in your test case. There isn't really much we can or want to do about this. Note that you can replace wget with a plain cat and it will still show the same behavior.
>
> The short version is that this is an inherent issue with streaming of zip files and something that won't be fixed.

And [this comment](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/issues/1106#issuecomment-446266093) tells how to create a consistent ZIP-file with `bsdtar`:

To make `bsdtar` create consistent information, `--options zip:experimental` needs to be added to `bsdtar`'s zip file creation command:

```
bsdtar --format=zip --options zip:experimental -cf a.zip a.out a.txt
```

and then

```
cat a.zip | bsdtar -tvf -
```

shows correct permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  0 1001   1001        0 Feb 17 21:18 a.out
-rw-r--r--  0 1001   1001        0 Feb 17 21:18 a.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

[this is not really an answer yet, but I'll post it as such since it's impossible to format anything in comments]

`zip` is not the only format which creates problems when extracted from a non-seekable file. Here is an example with multi-session iso images, but there at least `bsdtar` is printing an **error message** and is exiting with a non-zero status. It should probably do the same with zip files; silently messing up the permissions is not acceptable IMHO.

```
$ echo a.out > a.out
$ genisoimage -quiet -R -o a.iso a.out
$ chmod 755 a.out
$ growisofs -M a.iso -R -quiet a.out
Executing 'genisoimage -C 16,176 -M /dev/fd/3 -R -quiet a.out | builtin_dd of=a.iso obs=32k seek=11'
Rock Ridge signatures found
builtin_dd: 176*2KB out @ average infx1352KBps
a.iso: copying volume descriptor(s)

$ cat a.iso | bsdtar xf -
bsdtar: Ignoring out-of-order file @19 (a.out) 51200 < 411648
bsdtar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
$ ls -l a.out; hd a.out
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ahq ahq 6 Dec 11 19:15 a.out
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00                                 |......|
00000006

$ bsdtar xf a.iso
$ ls -l a.out; hd a.out
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ahq ahq 6 Dec 11 19:15 a.out
00000000  61 2e 6f 75 74 0a                                 |a.out.|
00000006
```

Comment: According to http://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/issues/1106#issuecomment-446219915, it means `libarchive` creates ZIP archives with inconsistent metadata.

Comment: I'd recommend editing this into the question as a useful way to recreate a test environment, actually.

Comment: @GolarRamblar that's not my interpretation of it. `bsdtar` should create standard zip files by default; it's when extracting from a non-seekable file that it should process the central directory at the end and treat as an **error** when that contains any attributes that could've overridden those from the per-file header.

Comment: @mosvy: Thanks for your better test case, I incorporated it into my question and removed it from your answer (edit still waits for approval).